# How to make a ROW scrollable left and right?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to make children of a Row widget display only X amount of children and make the widget scrollable?

[Here's an example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTUz8.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wrap row with SingleChildScrollView widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your `listview` inside a `SizedBox` widget with specific `height`, then you should configure your list to make it scroll in a horizontal way:

```
   SizedBox(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width  // This will make your list fill the screen horizontally
   height: 100.0 // you can edit it as you desire but it should be small to make the effect of scroll-able row
   child: listview.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, //This will make your list scroll on the horizontal axis
      itemCount: 10.0,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext content, int index) {

      // Your itemBuilder code here

      }
    ),
  ),
```